# Adding opacity effect to jquery slide animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to add opacity effect (from 0 to 1) to the code posted somewhere here (by users/1022305/trevor). No results yet (I'm still jquery beginner).

Here is the fiddle by the author of the code: http://jsfiddle.net/trevordowdle/S7n2b/

Any suggestions what line of code should be implemented? It is probably 1 line like:

```
opacity:'toggle'
```

tried this, wont work...

UPDATED Code:

```
// JavaScript Document

$(document).ready(function(){
var stop = true;
var hovered;
var timeout;


    $('.nav').hover(
        function(){
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            stop = true;
            hovered = this;
            timeout = setTimeout(function(){
            if($(hovered).hasClass('nav_menu_link_drop')){
                $('.content').css('z-index',0);
                $(hovered).next('.content').css('z-index',5);        
                $(hovered).next('.content').slideDown({

                    duration: 400, 
                    easing: 'jswing', 
                    });
                timeout = setTimeout(function(){
                    $('.content').not($(hovered).next('.content')).slideUp({
                    duration: 200, 
                    easing: 'easeInSine', 
                    });
                },100);

                $(hovered).next('.content').fadeIn(100);
            }
            else
                $('.content').slideUp(350);    
            },400);
        },
        function(e){
            stop = false;
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            setTimeout(function(){
                if(!stop)
                    $('.content').slideUp(350);
                    $('.content').fadeOut(350);
            },500);
        }
    );

    $('.content').hover(
        function(){
            stop = true;    
        },
        function(){

        }
    );

    $('#nav_menu').hover(
        function(){

        },
        function(){
            timeout = setTimeout(function(){
                $('.content').slideUp(350);
            },200);
        }
    );
});
```

So I added this 2 lines of code:

```
$(hovered).next('.content').fadeIn(100);
```

and

```
$('.content').fadeOut(350);
```

It isn't working :(

Comment: Really can't understand what you try to achieve..

Comment: I try to achieve an effect similiar to this one: http://jsfiddle.net/jc55L/2/

Comment: `toggle` is not a valid option for `opacity`. Update your question with some code like what have you tried so far.

Comment: Check my code given in answer

Answer (score 0):

The code that changes the opacity in the same way as the example fiddle is:

```
$( "yourdivname" ).fadeIn();
```

and

```
$( "yourdivname" ).fadeOut();
```

but without some code showing what youve tried so far I can't explain how you would use it
for your personal situation

Comment: I added the the code but there is no effect, any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

See this Sample :

http://jsfiddle.net/S7n2b/84/

I have give the id for each li

```
<li id="d0"><a class="nav_menu_link nav">Home</a></li>
<li class="nav_menu_link_drop nav" id="d1">
    <a class="nav_menu_link">DropDown 1</a>
</li>

$('#d1').hover(
function(){
    $('#content1').fadeIn();
     $('#content2').fadeOut();
}
```

);

```
$('#d0').hover(
function(){
    $('#content1').fadeOut();
     $('#content2').fadeOut();
}
```

);

```
$('#d2').hover(
function(){
    $('#content1').fadeOut();
    $('#content2').fadeIn();
}
```

);

```
$('#nav_menu').hover(
 function(){

},function(){
    $('#content1').fadeOut();
     $('#content2').fadeOut();
}
```

);

Comment: In your sample code there is only effect of fadein/fadeout. What I try to achieve is fadein/fadeout + slideDown/slideUp